# Create link to my website embedded video and start playing

Tags: html, iframe, video, hyperlink, embed

I have the following video iFrame embed code on a page on my website (mywebsite.com/page2) - it plays a video that is hosted on an external site (http://wistia.com). I want to be able to send email clients a link to my video on my page (mywebsite.com/page2/mywebsitevideolink) - not a link to the external website, a link that opens up mywebsite.com/page2 and displays the video on my page that you would have to scroll down to see and starts playing it. How can this be accomplished? Thanks.

```
<p class="rtecenter"><iframe allowfullscreen=""
allowtransparency="true" class="wistia_embed" frameborder="0"
height="480" mozallowfullscreen="" msallowfullscreen=""
name="wistia_embed" oallowfullscreen="" scrolling="no"
src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/myvideo" webkitallowfullscreen=""
width="640"></iframe></p> "
```

Comment: So you just want to embed a video that plays when you scroll to the bottom of the page?

Comment: I have the video embedded half way down the page, I want a link to be able to display that part of the page and start playing the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `p` tag to `<p class="rtecenter" id="video">`and then your link is http://mywebsite.com/page2#video

Hope that this'll help you.

You can also set up a file which displays when you type `/page2/mywebsitevideolink` and redirects to `/page2#video`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. When I click a link now, it automatically scrolls to the right part of the page.  The only other thing I would like to work is for it to autoplay after the link is clicked.

Comment: Just as David Corbin said: you have to look into wistia's documentation. But this task will likely require you to write some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link to a certain part of your page, just use an anchor link.

```
<div name="videopart">
VIDEO HERE
</div>
```

And for the link: http://yoursite.com/video.html#videopart

And for the player to autoplay, if you are using your video hosting's player, look in teir documentation for how to autoplay. If your just using the html  tag, and the word autoplay in the beginning tag.

Comment: If I add the word autoplay will it only autoplay when the email link is clicked or will it also autoplay when the page is loaded by someone just entering the URL?

Comment: It will autoplay when the page loads.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I'm looking for autoplay to happen only when a user clicks a link to the video, not when the page loads when a user just enters a URL into the browser.  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: I don't know specific syntax for that, but a good place to start would be the javascript `scrollTop` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop